# VBA Access: function concatenate tbl name and various fields

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

Here is my function:

```
Public Function checkIfNoll(tbl As DAO.Recordset, field As AccessObject, variable As Variant)
    If IsNull(tbl!field) Then
        variable = 0
    Else
        variable = tbl!field
    End If
End Function
```

I have a sql statement as such:

```
Set tblHLstrat = Nothing
sqlString2 = "SELECT [MR_PL] as mrPL, [Daily_Return_%] as mrDailyReturn, [MR_Comm] as mrComm & _ 
FROM tblNav_Calc WHERE tblNav_Calc.[Nav Date] = #" & tradeDate & "#"
Set tblHLstrat = db.OpenRecordset(sqlString2)
```

I want to feed my vba code:

variable = checkIfNoll(tblHLstrat, mrPL(each field selected in SQL, will call function over and over again), Variable)

I am unable to concatenate the table name and respective field names as my function variable. If someone could help me that would be great.

Essentially the function checks to make sure fields (1, 2, 3,... n) isn't null. if it is null, the variable(n) will be set to 0. if it is not null, variable (n) will be equal to the field value.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use the existing Access function `Application.Nz` which does the same thing?

Comment: Alternatively, if you're actually wanting to change the value that's retained in the table, you could construct a `For Each field In tblHLstrat.Fields` loop that includes the statement `If IsNull( field.Value ) Then field.Value = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Like Mark Wickett wrote in his comment, you want the NZ() function. It does exactly what you do in your custom function and works perfectly in queries. I have so many NZ() in my queries. So so many.

Nz(variable, valueIfNull)

Your query would look like this:

```
"SELECT [MR_PL] as mrPL, [Daily_Return_%] as mrDailyReturn, [MR_Comm] as mrComm & _ 
FROM tblNav_Calc 
WHERE tblNav_Calc.[Nav Date] = #" & Nz(tradeDate, 0) & "#"
```